# Conda Build fails packaging C++ project

Tags: c++, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I'm trying to create a recipe for the library here: https://github.com/hyrise/sql-parser

I'm building for OSX 10.13.

My `build.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
make VERBOSE=1
make DESTDIR="$PREFIX" install
```

I've also set up my SDK as per here: https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/compiler-tools.html#macos-sdk

I can build the project fine outside of conda build, however conda build fails with the below issue:

```
x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0-clang++ -std=c++1z -Wall -Werror -O3 -fPIC -c -o src/SQLParser.o src/SQLParser.cpp
In file included from src/SQLParser.cpp:2:
In file included from src/SQLParser.h:4:
In file included from src/SQLParserResult.h:4:
In file included from src/sql/SQLStatement.h:4:
In file included from /Users/j/miniconda3/envs/p37/conda-bld/sql-parser_1583094509703/_build_env/bin/../include/c++/v1/vector:265:
In file included from /Users/j/miniconda3/envs/p37/conda-bld/sql-parser_1583094509703/_build_env/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:90:
/Users/j/miniconda3/envs/p37/conda-bld/sql-parser_1583094509703/_build_env/bin/../include/c++/v1/wchar.h:119:15: fatal error: 'wchar.h' file not found
#include_next <wchar.h>
              ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [Makefile:66: src/SQLParser.o] Error 1
```

I can see wchar.h is in that dir

```
JMBA:v1 j$ ls -l /Users/j/miniconda3/envs/p37/conda-bld/sql-parser_1583094509703/_build_env/bin/../include/c++/v1 | grep wchar
-rw-rw-r--  41 j  staff    6272 28 Oct  2018 cwchar
-rw-rw-r--  41 j  staff    8080 28 Oct  2018 wchar.h
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: The error message points out `#include_next` which means that the compiler is trying to find the `wchar.h` file, probably in the system standard include directory. You might need to set `CONDA_BUILD_SYSROOT` to point to the place where you put the SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find a way to get -I$BUILD_PREFIX/include to the invocation of g++ / gcc